# CosmosDB migration MERN-Can't read collections

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm exporting a database from mlabs to CosmosDb.

after failing with other methods, I finally exported via mongodump and imported into CosmosDb. I can read the collections in studio 3t.

but when connecting in Express/mongoose via the connectionString, the collections all return [].

I've added my IP to the firewall.

It's not the code, when I point back to the mlab db everything retrieves correctly.

what am I missing in CosmosDb?

Answer (score 0):

issue also located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/153583/cosmosdb-migration-mern-can39t-read-collections.html?childToView=154602#answer-154602

in azure, the generated connection strings don't quite match what the exercise sent by Kaylan sent. and I also wasn't setting some of the options. without the options I get a message "Password contains an illegal unescaped character"

the Primary Connection string and Secondary Connection String add the following:

```
&retrywrites=false
&maxIdleTimeMS=120000
&appName=@<appName>@
```

once I removed that from the connection string ***AND*** used the options, things worked.
my final connection example:

```
//pulled from config for clarity
const config = {
    'database': process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://<user>:<password>@<db>.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb'
}

mongoose.connect(config.database, //with  user and pass inside
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        retryWrites: false,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useCreateIndex: true
    })
    //.then(() => console.log('Connection to CosmosDB successful'))
    .catch((err) => console.error('CosmosDB error:', err))
```